# Inno Setup : how to integrate admin credentials in the installer

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, admin, elevated-privileges

I want to create an installer that:
- install a software package
- copy a host file in the user system
without any user installation except launching the installer.

I need this installer to run as admin but I do not want to disclose the admin login/password to users but instead I want to embed it in the installer itself. How can I insert the admin credentials within the installers, please ? Is it even possible ?

I've looked into the forums but did not find what I'm trying to do.
Thank you for your help and support,
Fred

Comment: If you are asking if you can create an Inno Setup installer that can install as administrator from a non-administrator account without prompting for credentials, the answer is "no." (That would be a huge security hole!)

Answer (score 1):

You basically need this:
[Make Inno Setup installer request privileges elevation only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556853/850848)
(the old code in the second part of my answer with an explicit code for the elevation for Inno Setup 5)

Except that instead of simply re-running the installer with `runas` verb (which needs entering the Administrator credentials manually), you need this:
[Inno Setup run/execute code as another user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28510237/850848)